# Send linux Commands through SSHShellStream and return only the results

Tags: linux, powershell, ssh

I am writing adding functions to a powershell script that needs to send commands to remote Linux VMs and get versions of various software. I am close - I have the commands, but am having trouble getting back only the results. I am using Posh-ssh to do this.
For clarity and to avoid wasting anyone's time, I cannot use sshPass or putty. It has to be a powershell script, and I have to use sshSession and SSHShellStream.

My current script returns all of the lines from the linux terminal, but I only want the results of the command. Here is my functioning script, with sensitive info removed.

```
$linuxCreds = #function to retrieve admin credentials to ssh to linux box
$waitOnSSH = 5

$theSession = New-SSHSession -ComputerName <IP Address> -Credential $linuxCreds -AcceptKey:$true

if($theSession) {
   Start-Sleep -Seconds $waitOnSSH
   $theShellStream = New-SSHShellStream -sshsession $theSession
   if($theShellStream){
      Start-Sleep -Seconds $waitOnSSH
      $results = ""
      #Checking McAfee Version
      $theShellStream.WriteLine("rpm -qa --queryformat '%{version}-%{release}\n' MFEcma")
      Start-Sleep -Seconds $waitOnSSH
      $results += $theShellStream.read()
      
      Write-Host "Results: " + $results
   }

   #End SSH Session
   Remove-SSHSession -SSHSession $theSession > $null
}else{
   Write-Host "Could not establish session"
}
```

My current returned results are:

```
Results:
Last login: Fri Oct 20 03:52:46 CDT 2023 from <IP Address> on pts/0
Last login: Fri Oct 20 03:53:19 2023 from <IP Address>
<m -qa --queryformat '%{version}-%{release}\n' MFEcma
<VersionNumber>
[UserName@ComputerName ~]$
```

I only want VersionNumber, not any of the other lines Is there a way to get only that? I am checking multiple software versions on multiple computers, but if I can get the first one, I figure I can get the rest. Thanks for any help

Comment: I assume version number is of the the format `1.2.3`(digits separated by dots) ryt? If yes did you try using `regex` to extract it out?

Comment: it is that format. I have not tried regex, no. I have very limited linux experience, but I will start looking into that

Comment: Managed to figure it out. I didn't have to use regex, I used Invoke-SSHCommand instead, with the command set to a variable being pulled from an xml file. Looks like :  $results = Invoke-SSHCommand -Command $command -SSHSession $theSession

Comment: That's great! Post it as the solution to your question if it's working

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that. I've never managed ti answer my own question. I'll poke around and find it

Comment: Just add in the what are the steps you took that took you to the answer and if possible just showcase it with some small demo just so that if someone in future faces the similar issue they can benefit from your answer

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this using Invoke-SSHCommand, with command being a variable pulled from an xml file. It is not fully "complete". My next step is also pulling the software name and linking it to the version. Code so far (would go inside the above loop of if($theShellStream){:

```
$versionCmd = $operatingSystem.Section.Software.VersionCmd
Foreach($command in $versionCmd){
$results = Invoke-SSHCommand -Command $command -SSHSession $theSession
Write-Host $results.Output
}
```